# expo command not found when running expo --version after installing

Tags: expo

when I run the `sudo npm install -g expo-cli` command and enter my password, I can see that expo has shown up in the package.json however when I run the `expo --version`, the terminal says command not found. (on Mac)

I've googled loads on this and found so many articles about having to fix path in bash, but that part is just out of my scope of knowledge/understanding. Anyone who knows how to go around this issue and finally install expo? Ran som other commands that only initiated an infinite loop of expo installing globally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anything working on bash should work on Mac as well. Isn't it?

Comment: Why are you installing `expo` with `sudo`, I think it is being installed on root user and isn't available on your user. Try to install without sudo and then check if it works or not.